# error while playing ansible playbook

Tags: amazon-web-services, python, shell, ansible

I just installed ansible on a server in aws and then created a playbook to run the same but while running i am getting error as below :

```
ERROR! 'copy' is not a valid attribute for a Play

The error appears to have been in '/root/amritha/pega-cloud-infrastructure/ansible/roles/datadog-pegalogs-apptier/tasks/main.yml': line 3, column 3, but may
be elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.
```

The offending line appears to be:

```
- name: copy the pattern_search.txt file which has patterns to be grepped
  ^ here
```

And my playbook is as follows:

---

```
- name: copy the pattern_search.txt file which has patterns to be grepped
  copy: src=pattern_search.txt dest=/root/pattern_search.txt owner=root group=root mode=755

- name: copy the logsearchtest.sh script which greps patterns and prints pattern.txt file
  copy: src=logsearchtest.sh dest=/root/logsearchtest.sh owner=root group=root mode=755
  script: /root/logsearchtest.sh

- name: schedule cron to run every 5 minutes
  #cron: */5 * * * * root /root/logsearchtest.sh -c "script to grep patterns;"
  cron: name="logsearch script for grepping pega alert logs" minute="5" job="/root/logsearchtest.sh > /dev/null"

- name: copy parsers.py fucntion to datadog lib path
  copy: src=parsers.py dest=/opt/datadog-agent/agent/checks/libs/parsers.py owner=root group=root mode=755

- name: copy datadog agent configuration file
  copy: src=datadog-agent.conf dest=/etc/datadog.conf owner=root group=root mode=755
```

Also please note that I have a directory inside that I have `files` and `tasks` folder.  And the `files` folder has all mentioned files and `tasks` folder has the above playbook.

Comment: It's hard to tell with the poor formatting of your example but this seems like bad YAML syntax.

Comment: Actually, show us how you are executing this. Are you calling it directly from the command line? Are you using a playbook file? Show those.

Comment: what is ansible version? Carefully check again the indent of ansible statements. Also, post your inventory file and how you executed it

Comment: share your playbook.yml where you are calling above role. it seems you are having some syntax error there.

Answer (score 2):

I assume you are running ansible-playbook /blah/tasks/whatever.yml?

If so, that's your problem.
The proper structure for a playbook is:

```
---
name: my playbook
  roles:
    - Arole
    - Brole
# other playbok attributes
  tasks:
    - name: copy stuff
      copy: src=foo dest=bar
    - name: include cool tasks
      include: ../tasks/snafu.yml
      when: poobar == "fubar"
```